# how to add a server in eclipse juno?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have installed eclipse juno and trying to add server to it to do some javaEE exercises. I have JavaEE jdk installed. I am unable to find an aoption to add a server to it. I tried to find help from goolgle but could not find anything. I am using Juno bec eclipseEE is bit heavy for my pc.
how to add a server in eclipse juno ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to have the **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** package of Eclipse, regardless of which Eclipse version you use (Juno is the latest simultaneous release, based on Eclipse platform 4.2). The other packages don't include Java EE tools, such as launching servers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the server is the same in Juno version as in the previous eclipse version..

Just need to enable the server pane from the show perspective menu option.

Comment: I tried to locate in mentioned places i.e. Window > Show View > Servers OR ile > New > Other OR Window -> Preferences -> Server. But I am unable to find a server option. Eclipse is running simpel java OR GWT RPC programs so there seem no problem with installation but I am unble to find a server option.

Comment: Window --> Show View --> Others. It opens a popup "Show View". In that popup expand "Server" and select 'Servers'